# How to snap a text element to the edge of the parent of a text object in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

So I was wondering how to snap the score multiplier to the edge of the score like this:
[image: Score: 2500 x5]

I have tried to set the score multiplier to snap the the bounding box of the parent score text but it doesn't move when the score contains more digits. I am wondering is there is a way to scale the score bounding box to the size of the score text so the score multiplier stays at the top right.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the anchors and pivot in RectTransform, then if setup as a child of the score box the text will use that. You can use the text styling options to further align the text